# Explain if I understand correctly.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For a formula $ \gamma = r \leftrightarrow (p_1 \vee p_2) $ there is true that: $\rho \models \gamma $ iff $\rho(r) = \max(\rho(p_1), \rho(p_2))$

Is there exists such set of formulas $\Gamma$ that $\rho \models \Gamma$ iff $\rho(r) = \max_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (\rho(p_n))$ where $\rho$ is a vaulation.

Do I understand correctly that I should prove that there exists expected set that it is true $\rho(r) = \max_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (\rho(p_n))$ for **any** $r$?

$\rho \models \gamma $ means that $\rho$ satisfies $\gamma$

If yes, please hint me
If no, please explain what I should do.

Comment: What does it mean for a valuation $\rho$ to semantically entail a formula? E.g., what does $\rho \models \gamma$ mean?

Comment: @GitGud I edited

Comment: The mathematical statements are now ineligible, but I'm not quite sure that I understand your English. I think you understood it almost correctly. There does exist such a set $\Gamma$. **Hint:** It's a set with a single formula and it's similar to $\gamma$.

Comment: So, $\Gamma = \{r \leftrightarrow p_1 \vee ... \vee p_n \}$, yeah?

Comment: Damn auto-correct, I meant *intelligible*.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now that you guessed it, prove it.

Comment: It is pretty simple, isn't it? Just proving from definition of $\iff$ and $max$ definition.

Comment: Yes, it is. As all of mathematics, if you break it down enough, it's very simple. Note, however, that you should probably be using induction because the base case ($n=2$) is given to you right at the start.